# What is the grammar that generates the language quoted in the description?

Tags: logic

A doubt with question:

> What is the grammar that generates the language quoted in the description? $$a^nb^{n+m}c^m\text{ for }n≥0, m≥0$$

I don't understand this.

Comment: Do you know what a grammar is, and what a language is ?

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to find a grammar with rules that generate all the words of the form you describe, one example of theses words is $aabbbbbccc$ for $n=2$ and $m=5$.

The following grammar works, with initial symbol $S$ and variables 
$A,B$:

$\begin{array}{l}
S\to AB\\
A\to aAb\\
A\to\epsilon\\
B\to bBc\\
B\to\epsilon
\end{array}$

Where $\epsilon$ is the empty word.

For instance to obtain the word above, you can do $S\to AB\to aAbB\to aaAbbB\to aabbB\to aabbbCc\to aabbbbCcc \to aabbbbbCccc \to aabbbbbccc$.